# Android - set OnItemClickListener of ListView in widget

Tags: android, listview, widget

I created a widget containing a ListView, using RemoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(), RemoteViewsService and RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.

But I can't figure out how to set an OnItemClickListener to my ListView. The RemoteViews class has methods like setOnClickPendingIntent() for buttons etc. but no setOnItemClickPendingIntent() or something like that. Any ideas?

Comment: This is covered in detail on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#implementing_collections. See the section titled "Adding behavior to individual items"

Comment: I figured it out, turns out I had to use RemoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate() in my AppWidgetProvider and RemoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent() in the RemoteViewsFactory with the ID of the item set in the Intent extras.